# Third party scripts with Nextjs - Error - blocked by Cors policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager

I'm having a problem implementing a script handling tool from nextjs.
I followed the nextjs ( https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) documentation and used the worker (experimental) parameter to improve the page performance.
However, it gives me a blocked by Cors policy error.

CODE:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        strategy="worker"
        id="google-tag-manager"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var
              f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
              'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
              })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-NGZ3B84');`,
        }}
      />
....
....
....
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ysod.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A CORS policy like this means your domain is blocking references from outside domains. In this case the GTM container.

To allow references from outside sites you can set HTML Response Headers for your domain. Either an allow all header or a certain domain header would work

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:3000`